# Execute Check in Perl Test if (and only if) test case succeeds

Tags: perl, testing, teardown

I am using Test::Unit::TestCase for unit-testing in perl. Is there any way to do some special assertion in the tear_down sub, if - and only if - the current test succeeds so far.

```
sub set_up {
  my ($O_self) = @_;

  # prepare test case
}

sub tear_down {
  my ($O_self) = @_;

  # how to check if test succeeds so far?
  if (...) {
    $O_self->assert_something_special_for_all_tests();
  }
}

sub test_any1 {
   # some test
}

sub test_any2 {
   # some other test
}
```

Of course I can do the special check at the end of each test, but it would be much nicer to do it inside the tear_down so that I cannot forget the special check.

Comment: What is the special check you want to do?

Comment: In most of my tests I do some mocking. In the arange-part I define some expectations and after acting the test I want to assert, that all expectations are consumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test::Unit::TestCase hasn't been updated in 8 years. It doesn't use the normal Test::Builder infrastructure so it cannot be combined with other test modules.  Avoid it if possible.  If you want to do xUnit style testing in Perl, consider using [Test::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aClass) instead.

Because it is built using [Test::Builder](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aBuilder), you can access the underlying Test::Builder object and ask it for the state of the test.

```
sub teardown : Test(teardown) {
    my $self = shift;
    my $tb = $self->builder;

    my $all_tests_passing = !grep !$_, $tb->summary;
    do_something_extra if $all_tests_passing;
};
```